# How to set Cookie from Server side to Client side in NodeJS Express?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, token

i am trying to set cookie token to user browser in below way (from server side) for my nodejs application. But it doesn't work, I want to set cookies from server side for client browser. I was a newbie

Server side:

```
const authenticateUser = (req, res, next) => {
let data = req.body;
if (data.acc_name === users.acc_name && data.password === users.password) {
let secretKey = data.password;
let accessToken = jwt.sign(data, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
res.cookie('token', accessToken, {
maxAge: 3600000, 
httpOnly: true
>     });
res.send({ 'notice': 'Success' });
else {
res.status(401).send('Thông tin đăng nhập không hợp lệ.');
>   }
> };

app.post('/login', authenticateUser);
```

Client side:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let data = {
        acc_name: document.getElementById("acc_name").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
      };
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://localhost:443/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          const responseData = await response.json();
          document.getElementById("result").textContent = responseData.notice;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Invalid.";
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

How to set Cookie from Server side to Client side in NodeJS Express?

Comment: Hi, "its not working" doesn't help. Please include debugging details, and take a look at  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you and welcome here

Comment: I want to be able to set cookies from the server side to the client but it cannot assign cookies on the user browser side. that's what i expected